# remove duplicate items from postgres

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I need help writing the query to SELECT rows which have duplicate productIDs
the table is 4 columns

```
id,property_id,status,price
20,13356,sold,200000
24,78436,sold,730000
12504,13356,sold,200000
...
```

I currently have the following python script

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)


def get_dict_sql(cur, query, single=False):
    cur.execute(query)
    if single:
        return dict(cur.fetchone())
    z = cur.fetchall()
    return [dict(row) for row in z]


columns = ['property_id', 'status', 'price']
seen = set()
rows = get_dict_sql(cursor, "SELECT * FROM listings")
insert_statement = 'insert into listings_temp (%s) values %s'
for row in rows:
    if row['product_id'] in seen:
        continue
    seen.add(row['product_id'])
    values = [row[column] for column in columns]
    cursor.execute(insert_statement)
    q2 = cursor.mogrify(insert_statement, (AsIs(','.join(columns)), tuple(values)))
    cursor.execute(q2)

conn.commit()
```

I created a new table to store the new data and this script 26 hours ago and still didn't finish, is there a way of SELECT only rows where product_id is duplicated?
or even better a query which does directly in Postgres?

Comment: I am assuming you want to remove the data from database , so i am providing a url https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql/ , i created some testdata in table , it worked in my case . Before making permanent changes in table please have a look on transaction , how it works . Please avoid any typos. Have a great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **PostgreSQL** way to fetch duplicates:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=814e389fafaa29934635815a60a0b366)

This gives you duplicates:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id)
    FROM
        listings
) s
WHERE row_number >= 2
```

The [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) adds a row count to every element of a certain group (the `PARTITION`, which are the `product_id`s here). With that you are able to fetch only those, where the row count is `>= 2`

To remove the fetched record directly, you can combine the `SELECT` statement with a `DELETE` statement:

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0c3172e49316631229de5de1b8732f2d)

```
DELETE FROM t
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT
        id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id)
        FROM
            t
    ) s
    WHERE row_number >= 2
);
```

Comment: it works, is there a way to dump the rows (after removing the duplicates into a new table) into a new table?

Comment: `INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table` ? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d2b1152b13938b692f1e21170643aef0 (appended the INSERT example below)

Comment: @goku: You can combine the DELETE step and the INSERT step into one single query if you like: You can use WITH statement (CTE) for that: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1bda6af20a3c55399a5f1a729c0038d4 However, it could be slower than two separate calls (maybe in a transaction), it depends on many things, like data, system, ...